# Dealing with database access in transformer stacks

Tags: database, haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-persistent

This question is about `groundhog` or `persistent`, because I believe both share the same problem.

Say I have a transformer `Tr m a` that provides some functionality `f :: Int -> Tr m ()`. This functionality requires database access. There are a few options I can use here, and none are satisfactory.

I could put a `DbPersist` transformer somewhere inside of `Tr`. Actually, I'd need to put it at the top because there are no `PersistBackend` instances for standard transformers AND I'd still need to write an instance for my `Tr` newtype. This already sucks because the class is far from minimal. I could also lift every db action I do.

The other option is changing the signature of `f` to `PersistBackend m => Int -> Tr m ()`. This would again either require a `PersistBackend` instance on my `Tr` newtype, or lifting.

Now here's the real issue. How do I run `Tr` inside of a context that already has a `PersistBackend` constraint? There's no way to share it with `Tr`.

I can either do the first option and run the actual `DbPersist` transformer inside of `Tr` with some new connection pool (as far as I can tell there's no way to get the pool from the `PersistBackend` context I'm already in), or I can do the second option and have the run function be `runTr :: PersistBackend m => Tr m a -> m a`. The second option would actually be completely fine, but the problem here is that the `DbPersist`, that will eventually have to be somewhere in the stack, is now under the `Tr` transformer and there are no `PersistBackend` instances for the standard transformers of which `Tr` is made of.

What's the correct approach here? At the moment is seems that the best option is to go with a sepatare `ReaderT` somewhere in the stack that provides me with the connection pool on request and then do `runDbConn` with that pool everywhere where I want to access the DB. Seeing how `DbPersist` basically already is just a `ReaderT` I don't see the sense in having to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### groundhog

I recommend using the [latest groundhog](https://github.com/lykahb/groundhog/blob/master/groundhog/Database/Groundhog/Core.hs) from their `master` branch. Even though the change I'm about to describe appears to have been implemented in Sept. 2015, no release has made it to Hackage. But the authors seemed to have tackled this very problem.

On tip, `PersistBackend` is now a much simpler class to implement, much reduced from the dozens-of-methods-long behemoth it once was:

```
class (Monad m, Applicative m, Functor m, MonadIO m, ConnectionManager (Conn m), PersistBackendConn (Conn m)) => PersistBackend m where
  type Conn m
  getConnection :: m (Conn m)

instance (Monad m, Applicative m, Functor m, MonadIO m, PersistBackendConn conn) => PersistBackend (ReaderT conn m) where
  type Conn (ReaderT conn m) = conn
  getConnection = ask
```

They wrote an instance for `ReaderT conn m` (`DbPersist` has been deprecated and aliased to `ReaderT conn`), and you could as easily write one for `Tr (ReaderT conn)` if you choose to go the route of putting `ReaderT` inside rather than outside. It's not quite an `mtl` monad transformer since you would have to instance `Tr m` instead of `Tr`, but this and the associated data type trick they're using should allow you to use a custom monad stack without too much fuss.

Either option you choose will probably require some lifting. In my personal opinion I would stick `ReaderT conn` on the very outside of the stack. That way, the `mtl` helpers can still lift through most of your stack and you can glue on an additional lift to take it home. And, if you were to stick with the version on Hackage, this seems to be the only reasonable option since otherwise you would have the (old) monolithic `PersistBackend` class.

### persistent

Persistent is a little more straightforward: as long as the monad transformer stack contains `ReaderT SqlBackend` and terminates in `IO`, you can lift a call to `runSqlPool :: MonadBaseControlIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m a -> Pool SqlBackend -> m a`. All Persistent operations are defined to return something of type `ReaderT backend m a`, so the design sort of just works out.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. To fix this issue I've written my own class that's almost exactly the `PersistBackend` in groundhog. You just saved me the trouble of answering my own question. Accepted!